# Different widths for same rem sizes in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website using floats only and no modern CSS like flexbox and CSS grids so that I can support maximum browsers. The markup I use to style my content in rows and columns looks something like this:

```
<div class = "row"> 
  <div class = "col-1-of-3">[Content]</div>
  <div class = "col-1-of-3">[Content]</div>
  <div class = "col-1-of-3">[Content]</div>
</div>
```

I am using custom classes for "row" and "col" and not using any other vendor css like Bootstrap etc. All widths are correct in Firefox and Chrome but in Edge and Internet Explorer, sometimes the widths are not correct while resizing the window. I have made a simple one line header to demonstrate this issue. I can not replicate the issue on codepen so I have this [link](https://float-f8e18.firebaseapp.com/).

It's a simple 3 column layout with floats. When you resize your window in Chrome and Firefox, the width is readjusted correctly but in Edge and Internet Explorer, there is constant glitching while resizing the window and the column layout is breaking.

Comment: Please include a [mre] with code here on Stack Overflow, not just on an external site. When that link goes stale, this question will lose its usefulness. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that the example runs here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use rem and calc(), check these props with [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

For example IE 11 has partial support for calc()